# If we could use electrons as information storage, how would we model a database?

Tags: data-structures, database-theory

It's not [completely](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/287/5452/463) [incredible](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/289/5484/1431) that electrons are accessible information storage units. So let's say there is a breakthrough and we suddenly have read/write access to every electron on the planet. They may each have a few GB of storage, and the "metadata" that keeps their integrity is negligible in size (and immutable, to avoid a nuclear disaster). Lets also assume that the communication between electrons are made at the speed of photons.

The question is now, how would we model a database on this? What differences would it have compared to the DB:s of today? What similarities? Would the possibilities for concepts like [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) increase?

Comment: You seem to mixing up the logical model with the physical. ACID is a logical property. The medium of storage is a physical. We'd model the logic of the database exactly the same. The difference might be that access times/latency/etc are shorter. Then there might be fewer conflicts/less locking. But we still couldn't exclude the possibility of collisions amongst long-running transactions. (where 'long-running' means greater than a picosecond ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about that. The difference is that you have a close to infinite number of small storage units instead of a limited number of arbitrary size, as it is today. This could take us closer to a model similar to Hadoop rather than the existing SQL/traditional RDBMS variants, but I'm interested in taking the thought even further.